# R tidyverse equivalent to Stata replace if missing

Tags: r, replace, tidyverse, stata

I am trying to find an R/tidyverse equivalent to Stata's `replace b = a if missing(b)`.

Say I have these data:

```
library(tidyverse)
data <- data.frame(a=c(1:8), b= c(1:5, NA, NA, NA))
```

I am trying to replace the missing values in `b` with the values in `a`. I try this:

```
data %<>% mutate(b = replace_na(b, a))
```

But get an error. What can I do in the `tidyverse` to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you're going about it I'd use `coalesce` from `dplyr`:

```
data %<>% mutate(b = coalesce(b, a))
```

Output:

```
data

  a b
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
4 4 4
5 5 5
6 6 6
7 7 7
8 8 8
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use `ifelse` in `mutate`:

```
data %>% 
  mutate(b = ifelse(is.na(b), a, b))
#>   a b
#> 1 1 1
#> 2 2 2
#> 3 3 3
#> 4 4 4
#> 5 5 5
#> 6 6 6
#> 7 7 7
#> 8 8 8
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

In `data.table`, an option is `fcoalesce`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, b  := fcoalesce(b, a)]
```